# D3 - reordering elements based on their data

Tags: d3.js

I have made a compound bar chart representing footballers within football teams. The chart is here: http://andybarefoot.com/football/path.html

I used d3 and built the page to work in two stages. Firstly I load the data and create a rectangle for each player. I then update the parameters of the rectangles based on the data assigned to each element depending on which view is chosen. This means that the different navigation options resize and rearrange the rectangles based on existing data mapped to the elements but no additional data is loaded in.

Whilst the resizing of the rectangles works correctly I am unable to reorder the rectangles based on the data.

The vertical position of each rectangle is set simply by "i" multiplied by a set spacing variable. To change the order I thought I could selectAll all elements, sort based on the relevant data, and then set the new vertical position in the same way. (i.e. the value of "i" would have changed). However I can't get this to work.

Here is my (unsuccessful) attempt:

```
// select all elements and then reorder
svg
   .selectAll(".team")
   .sort(function(a, b) { 
       return b.totalClubContractDistance - a.totalClubContractDistance;
   })
;
// select all elements and reposition according to new order
svg
    .selectAll(".team")
    .duration(750)
    .attr("transform", function(d,i) {
       return "translate(0,"+teamSpacing*i+")";
    })
;
```

Comment: It'll be better if you give a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

In d3 there are 4 core concepts.  Join, Update, Enter, Exit.  You can read more here: https://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/

Basically, every time you want to update the position of an element, you should change the data, then do a join followed by an update.

So the code would look like this:

```
function render (data) {
    // join
    // this joins the new data to the existing data
    var teams = svg.selectAll('.team')
        .data(data);

    // update
    // this will update existing teams that have a different location
    teams.attr('transform', function (d, i) {
        return 'translate(0, ' + teamSpacing * i + ')';
    });

    // enter
    // this will add new teams that were added to the data set
    teams.enter()
        .attr('transform', function (d, i) {
            return 'translate(0, ' + teamSpacing * i + ')';
        });

    // exit
    // this will remove all the teams that are no longer part of the data set
    teams.exit()
        .remove();

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @link! In this case I have already attached all the data but want to be able to toggle the order of the elements depending on 2 different data values. One view orders the elements by descending "totalBirthDistance", the other by descending "totalClubContractDistance". Should I still update the data? I only have one dataset so there would be no extra/fewer elements, just the same elements displayed in a different order.

Comment: You would update the dataset during reordering.  Think of the data as driving the d3 visualization.  If you want the visualization to change you have to update the data.